# How to fine-tune an ASP GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

I need a table on a webform, with one editable column.

I tried an HTML table, but with `tbody{height:150px; overflow:auto;}` it turns out that lining out the column headers with the columns in the body is hard, even harder with a `<input>` tag in the body. Also, the width of the `<input>` within the `<table>` is not changeable; the size option is about the number of characters allowed in the textbox.

I tried DevExpress, but there it is hard to get one editable column.

Now I am trying an ASP Gridview, but finding it hard to finetune the layout. This is the CSS in my new App_Themes:

```
table#GridView_Samples 
{
    table-layout:fixed;
    border:1px solid grey;  
}
table#GridView_Samples th
{
    font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px; font-style:normal;
}
table#GridView_Samples td
{
    font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px; font-style:normal;
    border:1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 0px, 5px 0px, 5px;
}
```

The font is changed correctly, except that the column headers are still boldface, and the padding did not work.

Could it be that the failing CSS options are overruled by the Microsoft default theme settings? And, in general, that it is not possible to finetune all aspects of ASP controls?

---

edit: here is a fragment of html output (prettyprint by hand):

```
            <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" Mode="NumericFirstLast" 
            border="1" id="GridView_Samples" 
            style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Project</th>
                        <th scope="col">Monster</th>
                        <th scope="col">Omschrijving</th>
                        <th scope="col">% Lutum (gemeten)</th>
                        <th scope="col">% Org.Stof (gemeten)</th>
                        <th scope="col">% Lutum (toetsing)</th>
                        <th scope="col">% Org.Stof (toetsing)</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:60px;">P-0002</td>
                        <td style="width:60px;">S-01</td>
                        <td style="width:150px;">Sample 01</td>
                        <td style="width:60px;">4</td>
                        <td style="width:70px;">20</td>
                        <td style="width:60px;">
                                <input name="GridView_Samples$ctl02$TextBoxLutum" type="text" 
                                id="GridView_Samples_TextBoxLutum_0" style="width:60px;" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:70px;">
                            <input name="GridView_Samples$ctl02$TextBoxOrganicMatter" type="text"
                            id="GridView_Samples_TextBoxOrganicMatter_0" style="width:70px;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Did you try `!important` ?

Comment: Is this an ASP option? How to use it? (Hard to google)

Comment: That goes in css: `th { font-style: normal !important; }`

Comment: If you find so many things hard at this point, an ASP grid-based app probably isn't a good starting point.

Comment: how does the grid render in HTML? please provide a sample of the HTML. it's nearly impossible to debug CSS without the corresponding HTML

Comment: @abhitalks tried it, did not improve anything.

Comment: @MikeHometchko Good Point, but at first ASP seems very simple. It solved 80% of my problem with just 20% of planned effort. However, I don't like some minute details such as the cell content with no padding to the gridlines, and boldface in the header...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use raw  HTML markup when you can use the actual GridView in your markup?  Here is a GridView I am using on a project currently:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" ID="theGrid" Width="100%" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="theGrid_Sorting" OnRowDataBound="theGrid_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name"
                        HeaderText="Name"
                        HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" 
                        SortExpression="Name" />
    ... more columns ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You can see how it has properties for you to set all the styling you need.

---

**Edit:**  To do certain specific things, like left padding, you still need to resort to CSS styling, but since the GridView creates cells upon data binding, you have to style them at runtime.  Use the RowDataBound event handler of the GridView and in it, try this:

```
foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
    cell.Style.Add("padding-left", "10px");
```

Comment: I must admit that the ASP control has many, many options, but the option I was looking for, padding-left, I could not find. With html/css, pretty much *everything* can be tuned. I ended up using a DevExpress control that happens to have some padding around cell values. Thanks for your info.

Comment: Glad you found a workable solution!  For future reference, I updated the answer to include how you would accomplish left padding in a GridView.